# Why did the onChange handler delay the local state update in the ToggleButtonsGroup mui component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, onchange, react-functional-component

I have a problem with the **ToggleButtonGroup component**  of the **material-ui** library, precisely in the **onChange handler**. At the beginning my code was more complex, I eliminated the problems one by one until I got this piece of code. But I can't understand the behavior of this code.

```
export default function ToggleButtons() {
    
    // setting local state
    const [values, setValues] = useState(()=>[]);

    // toggle buttons handler
    const onChangeHandler =(event: any,newValues: string[]) => {
        setValues(newValues);
        console.log('newValues',newValues);
        console.log('state values',values);
      };

    
    return (
        <ToggleButtonGroup
            value={values}
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
        >
            <ToggleButton value='first' >first</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton value='second' >second</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton value='third' >third</ToggleButton>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
    );
}
```

Visually everything is perfect. But inside there is something that intrigues me.

[image]

### But please check my console##

- **First button is checked**

[image]

- **First button is unchecked**

[image]

- **Second button is checked then the third**

[image]

***It seems that the local state is always delayed. Did I write something wrong? If not then where is the problem?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React updates state asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so your console.log is printing stale data.

If you use [React dev tools](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/react-developer-tools) to see your state, it's working correctly:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! There are so many things about react. But here I feel that I violated a rule hhh

Comment: I have to make some test before i accept

Comment: I used useEffect() hook to handle the state update and act accordingly [see this atricle](https://blog.logrocket.com/why-react-doesnt-update-state-immediately/)

Answer (score 0):

try to make useState statement exactly as in documentation.
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-toggle-button/

take a look =>
you did :
`const [values, setValues] = useState(()=>[])`
they did:

```
 const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState<string | null>('left');
```

why do you use array instead of just simple string?
look at their implementation:

```
import FormatAlignCenterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FormatAlignCenter';
import FormatAlignRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FormatAlignRight';
import FormatAlignJustifyIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FormatAlignJustify';
import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ToggleButtonGroup';

export default function ToggleButtons() {
  const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState<string | null>('left');

  const handleAlignment = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    newAlignment: string | null,
  ) => {
    setAlignment(newAlignment);
  };

  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      value={alignment}
      exclusive
      onChange={handleAlignment}
      aria-label="text alignment"
    >
      <ToggleButton value="left" aria-label="left aligned">
        <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="center" aria-label="centered">
        <FormatAlignCenterIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="right" aria-label="right aligned">
        <FormatAlignRightIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="justify" aria-label="justified" disabled>
        <FormatAlignJustifyIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

Comment: Same problem! But thank you. Actually the problem is related with react. It sometimes update state asynchronously. as mentioned by @Eduardo Motta de Moraes